# img src showing wrong user from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

**UPDATE** I added this to my while loop during the array fetch. Does this work, or is there a better way? It is showing the correct pic now:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if ($result) {
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         if($username == $row['username']) { //<--- NEW CODE
              $profile_pic = '<img src="' . $row['avatar'] . '" style = "width:70%" alt="Profile Photo"/>';
         }

     }
}
```

I tried to search for this, but couldn't find anything similar. I've edited nothing on my profile.php page. I created several test users to test the functionality of a live user search. Everything was working fine until I logged in as another user. The profile pic that is displayed in the browser is pointing to a different user, yet the real image path is correctly stored in the database. I deleted all users except for the original two, and nothing has changed. I haven't changed any code, but I will show the relevant code that displays the profile pic and the live search. 
(**Note**: I will work on more secure queries later. Learning to translate into prepared statements as I go.)

The pic container from profile.php. I'm even echoing the current username temporarily at the top left just to show that it's getting the correct name.

```
<div id="avatar-container" class="dsh-display-container">
   <button type="button" id="upload-toggle"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i><span>  Update Avatar  </span></button>
   <?php
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
   if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $profile_pic = '<img src="' . $row['avatar'] . '" style = "width:70%" alt="Profile Photo"/>';
         }
   }
   ?>
   <?php echo $avatar_form; ?>
   <?php echo $profile_pic; ?>
</div>
```

This is what is displaying on my profile:
[image: img src]

On my search.php page, it displays correctly.

[image: correct img]

This is what shows the info:

```
try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=devSocial", "xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die("ERROR: ".$e->getMessage());
}

if (isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] != "") {

$req = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE :username");
$req->execute(array(
    'username' => '%' . $_POST['username'] . '%'
));
if ($req->rowCount() == 0) {
    echo "Sorry. No one by that name found.";
} else {

while ($data = $req->fetch()) {
    $data['gender'] = ($data['gender'] == 'm') ? 'male' : 'female';

?>
<div class="user">
    <div class="img-container">
    <img src="<?php echo $data['avatar']; ?>" class="userImage">
    </div>
    <span class="username"><?php echo $data['username']; ?></span><br/>
    <span class="gender"><?php echo $data['gender'];?></span><br/>
    <span class="profession"><?php echo $data['profession']; ?></span><br/>
    <span class="uni"><?php echo $data['uni']; ?></span><br/>
    <span class="degree"><?php echo $data['degree']; ?></span><br/>
    <span class="major"><?php echo $data['major']; ?></span><br/>
    <hr/>

</div>
```

I completely removed testUser from the database, and the profile displays correctly.

[image: correct img]

My main concern is that I changed nothing in those two segments of code and I was able to alternate between users. What is this voodoo? I've logged in as the two different users off and on for weeks and it showed correctly. I even went over my local history with a fine toothed comb and nothing has been changed. If someone could help that would be great because I've spent far too long. If I delete all but my "csheridan" user, it works. If I delete then recreate the testUser, my "csheridan" user now shows the default avatar. This is a major bug and I'm lost.

Comment: Hi! So in your profile.php, your query returns *all* users, and you assign `$profile_pic` in a while loop... Your variable will always contain the *last* user's avatar - based on some internal MySQL sorting order of the returned list of users... Could that be your problem?

Comment: Try deleting your cache.

Comment: Your photo query is getting all your users: `$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";` Fix that

Comment: Tried deleting cache. I believe you guys are correct with my query though. I'll go work on that and get back to you.

Comment: I'm going to edit my question to show what I've done because it shows correctly now, but I would like to know if this is the best way to do so. Please see "UPDATE" in question.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're using mysqli_ in one code, then switching over to PDO after?

Comment: and why are you using LIKE rather than an exact user in the `WHERE` clause? that might bring some unexpected results.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was for the user search page. It displays all users with the characters in their name that are typed. Is there a better way?

Comment: stick to one api. You're probably getting disconnected somewhere. I suggest you use sessions in a WHERE clause for all SELECTs, and destroy the session on logout.

Comment: what you are doing now (after the update) is indeed correct.

Comment: better way would be to query using `WHERE` and get only row specific to that user, since that looks like a profile page for a specific user, thats all you should need.

Comment: @coderodour Sorry if I didn't clarify. The 'LIKE' clause is on search.php, and it displays all users with similar names.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I mentioned in my question that I'm learning outside of mysql_* as I go. All deprecated mysql_* will be removed eventually and replaced with more secure code. I have prepared statements for all other pages except the ones shown. Just have to learn the syntax. :-)

Comment: again; if you're looking to show an image for a specific user, don't use LIKE. How does your login system work btw? You using `password_hash()` I hope? or how does your login work?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I get what you're saying now. And yes, I'm using password_hash() and password_verify. No way I'm doing my own hashing/salts.

Comment: great. Well, I don't see `password_verify()` in your second PDO code. If you're not using that, then you need to do that. When they login and are verified, assign a session array to the POST username, and then query based on that with a `WHERE user='session_name'`, That is pseudo code of course. Then create a separate file for them to logout and destroy the session.

Comment: addendum to the above: you can also assign a session array to the image/avatar column in question.

Comment: Yep. I've done both of those in my login.php and logout.php (verify and $_SESSION as well as destroying). Thank you for keeping me on my toes. :-)

Comment: so, would you call this matter resolved? remember to ping me; I only kept this tab open for this instance @IRGeekSauce

Comment: @Fred-ii-  eeetee posted my solution as a comment, so I can't accept, but yes, it's resolved.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce I see. Well, I didn't what to say earlier when you mentioned that that was only based on a search. I did mention the fact of using a `WHERE` clause. I'm not saying this because of possible rep (gain), but merely stating the fact that without a "specific" `WHERE` clause, would do just as they said. You can always ping them if you want and to post an answer, yet to be more specific than what their comment read as.

Comment: @eeetee If you'll post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce sorry, just seen this. I added it. If you don't accept it, it's perfectly fine :)

Comment: @eeetee Accepted. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your photo query is getting all your users:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
```

This needs to be fixed

Comment: How would you suggest fixing this? SO is not a place just to point out issues and not provide solutions;... that's kind of the point of this website ! `:-D`

Answer (score 0):

The user never returned to post his comment as an answer, so I'll post it here. It was actually a combination of comments.

When I ran my query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
```

it gets all users from the DB. And during my original while loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {
    $profile_pic = '<img src="' . $row['avatar'] . '" style="width:70%" alt="Profile Photo"/>';
```

it was always returning the last user in the database.

This is what fixed it. I added an if condition to match the row specifically to the current username:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if ($result) {
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         if($username == $row['username']) { //<-- THIS RIGHT HERE
             $profile_pic = '<img src="' . $row['avatar'] . '" style = "width:70%" alt="Profile Photo"/>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo $avatar_form; 
                echo $profile_pic;
```

If any people search for this question, please use more secure code. I'm learning PDO and prepared statements, and the code will be replaced with it later.